# Circular import error with some not familar error

Tags: python, import, specifications, circular-dependency

`/usr/local/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'system.__main__' (ImportError: cannot import name 'LANG' from partially initialized module 'system' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Black-Lightning/system/__init__.py))`

First of all I'm not familiar with 1st error and I don't have module with same name system
and I didn't imported from system to system, some thing wrong in docker file or with shell files? ( learning )

## Shell

````
#!/bin/bash

if [ -e exconfig.py  ]
then
    a="""
LOADING USERBOT  - KINDLY WAIT 5min. 
INITIALIZING - Self Hosting Setup 
© Black-Lightning 2021"""
    


else
    a =     """LOADING USERBOT  - KINDLY WAIT 5min. 
USERBOT -  Black-Lightning
© Black-Lightning 2021"""


fi


echo a
git clone https://github.com/KeinShin/Black-Lightning -b rebirth 
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/*


cd Black-Lightning

echo "Installing Requirements"

pip3 install -r requirements.txt && pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt







echo "INITIALIZING System"
python3 -m system```
````

Answer (score 0):

can you please share your contents inside requirements.txt and what all libraries are being imported in project Black-Lightning. This issue seems to be an issue of circular import.
I will try to give you an overview of what circular import is and the way you can avoid or debug this in your code.

Circular import occurs when two modules depend on each other. Let's say you have two modules ( can be from the external libraries you use or from your codebase )
and they look like below: -

```
# module1
import module2

def function1():
    module2.function2()

def function3():
    print('Goodbye, World!')
```

---

```
# module2
import module1

def function2():
    print('Hello, World!')
    module1.function3()
```

Let's say that you have a **init**.py that is calling module1.function1(), in this case, what is gonna happen is that while calling function1(), it will see that a function from module2 is being called named as function2(). So it will import that come to function2(). But remember python hasn't reached function3() of module1. So when function3() of module1 is being called from function2() of module1, it throws an error.

This is an instance of circular import because of the modules present inside your code. It is possible to have the same scenarios while using different versions of different libraries.

To avoid this kind of problem, I will suggest two things strongly: -

1. **NEVER** try to have imports like **"from xyz import *"**
2. If you have multiple modules inside your code try to mention the
   exact path while importing them.
   **DON'T** :-> from xyz import a, b, c

   **DO** :-> from <MODULE_PATH>/xyz import a, b, c
3. To debug the issue for Circular import, you can try using [Module Finder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/modulefinder.html). This can help you list down all the dependencies from your project then you can go through and see which ones are conflicting
4. Another obvious way to debug this issue is by running your application in verbose mode by using a command similar to **python -v <script_name>.py**

Hopefully, these steps might help you resolve your issues. Please reach out in the comments if any other clarifications required.

Reference:-
[Python Circular Imports](https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/)

Comment: Can you please comma seperate them, it's a bit confusing. And can you also share the imports from your project as well

Comment: and your explanation preety good, now i know what to do thanks buddy!

Comment: ```heroku3,   art, bs4, html5lib, requests, GitPython, holidays, schedule, pycountry, better_profanity, translate,e textblob, telegraph ```

Comment: is ```/usr/local/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'system.__main__``` connected with circular import?

Comment: yeah because there is circular import, some dependencies are not able to be recognised