# Python imports in nested structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

There is the following structure:

```
project/
   I-----main.py
   I-----src/
          I----__init__.py (empty)
          I----util.py
          I----shared/
                  I----__init__.py (empty)
                  I----hello.py 


#main.py
from src import util

#util.py (runs without errors)
from shared import hello

#hello.py (runs without errors)
def hello():
    print("Hello")
```

I try to run main.py, get result

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shared'

How to repair imports in main.py?

Comment: Why are there two ``__init__.py``s? Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164258/is-it-not-possible-to-define-multiple-constructors-in-python

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget one `__init__.py` per package, that looks correct to me. `__init__.py` is **not** a constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found possible solution (works well):

```
    #util.py
    import sys
    from pathlib import Path
    
    root = Path(__file__).parent.parent #depends on file's place in general structure
    sys.path.append(str(root))
    import src.shared.hello as hello
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two main reasons for such kind of failures:

1. **Module import:** You are not importing the module correctly. You can either import it using the `__init__.py` of a module by mentioning the import of its sub-module or you can directly put the full path via an import. For instance, you can use `from src.shared import hello`. Or, in your `__init__.py` file, inside the `src` module, you could add `from shared import hello`. This will also work because whenever you import a module, the first thing that is being run in that module is the `__init__.py` of that file.
2. **Circular imports:** This is not your case, but I am bringing this up because many times we ignore this and get trapped. A circular import occurs when two modules depend on each other. I have described why it happens and how to avoid it in the post, [What is Circular Import and how to avoid it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67544089/circular-import-error-with-some-not-familar-error/67544359#67544359).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to `from src.shared import hello`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29025223)

Comment: @mufazmi: This one does provide an answer. That said, [subsequently contributed answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67636545/3025856) reiterate this suggestion but with a lot more detail.

Comment: it isnt a stable and always working solution

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a relative import:

```
from .shared import hello
```

If you run `util.py` normally, `.../project/src` is appended to `sys.path` and Python can find the import. However, when you run `main.py`, `.../project/` is appended to `sys.path`, and Python can't find the `shared` module. By using a relative import, Python looks up the module name relative to the current package, and can find the `shared` module.

See also: [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)